# CSS и JavaScript браузера Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, material-design

Всем известно, что `Google Chrome` уже давно переведен на `Material Design`.
Где можно скачать `css и js` с помощью которых создаются служебные страницы браузера, то есть настройки, расширения и т.д.?

Comment: Первое, что нагуглилось: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite

Comment: В хроме в материале в исходниках все очень запутанно и нет привычного фрэймворка. У гугла есть `anguarjs + material` - все элементы там аналогичны

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, можно ссылку на material framework?

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/